# Excel C# Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a program that uses a dynamically created reports in excel, and prints them out to a pdf.  I am having a problem with some of the reports that run for 4-5 hrs.  Excel memory usage starts to exceed the system limits, and I can not determine a way of clearing some of the memory without killing the application process.  Does anyone have any incite? I can't kill and restart Excel process because my objects, in the Excel Object in C#, need to persist some information.  THanks.

Comment: please provide more information, some source code... what have you tried so far ? memory profiler ? any exceptions/error messages ?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, but excel hangs when the memory exceeds system limits.  I have tried quiting excel, GC.Collect().

Comment: did you use a memory profiler on your code since you write that you need to persist some information in C# ? some source code esp. of the parts that interact with excel and/or persists some info would help in understanding/solving this

Comment: Do you generate all the data and then write it? Might be better to chunk it up if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest that you can prepare your data in database first, because the dynamically invoking is really slow.

Just let your excel api application to do the works about display and convert.

Did you try using `excel.Visible = true` to show the excel UI?